# How do I auto-compile .coffeescript with Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

I enjoy writing my stack in CoffeeScript, I'm just wondering how I can get it to auto compile at run time with Node.js so I don't have to manually compile every coffee file I edit and move the .js into the file, this is what I have right now (just for a test);

---

```
/routes/index.coffee:
```

---

```
exports.index = (req, res) ->
  res.render "index",
    title: "Express"
```

---

```
app.js:
```

---

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
require('coffee-script');
var express = require('express')
  , staticp = require('./routes/index')
  , user = require('./routes/user')
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path');

var app = express();

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

app.get('/', staticp.index);
app.get('/users', user.list);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});


Error: 

https://gist.github.com/Gacnt/8f550196813df8fe1d5f
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just `require('coffee-script');` beforehand.

UPDATE :
If you're using CoffeeScript >=1.7.0, you need to `register()` it.

Comment: I did that, now I'm getting this error: https://gist.github.com/Gacnt/8f550196813df8fe1d5f

Comment: exports.index = (req, res) ->
  res.render "index",
    title: "Express"

Comment: that's the only coffee file you have ?

Comment: yeah, just for the routers

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30624/discussion-between-xcritics-and-user1737909)

Comment: sorry, I got to go. I'll notice you when I come back if nobody's answered by then :).

Comment: Figured it out, it was because I left the /* */ in the coffee file by accident :/

Answer (score 5):

You can start `coffee -wc *.coffee` which will recompile .coffee files when they are saved.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the 'at runtime' part, but I left the answer because it might be useful to someone.